# PingFederate IDP Config with LDAP

Tags: pingfederate

I am trying to get a test instance of PingFederate working. I am having an issue with LDAP auth. I have a single server hosting my AD and PF-IDP and a separate server hosting my SP. I have setup htmlformadapter for my test purposes. So, when I hit my SP initiated SSO url like:
https://SPSERVER:9031/sp/startSSO.ping?PartnerIdpId=sppartner

I get redirected to the 
https://IDPSERVER:9031/idp/SSO.saml2

and I get to see the html form. When I enter valid credentials like 
user: ADuser
pwd: ADpwd

I get `we didn't recognise the username or password ....` error. On the server logs, I see
`11:18:20,610 DEBUG [LDAPUsernamePasswordCredentialValidator] search sAMAccountName=guest`
`11:18:20,610 DEBUG [LDAPPasswordCredentialValidatorResult] LDAP error authenticating user in 'MyDC01'.  The response was interpreted as 'authn.srvr.msg.user.not.found'.`

if I enter my user name as `Domain\User`, it gets garbled in the logs like below
`11:18:20,610 DEBUG [LDAPUsernamePasswordCredentialValidator] search sAMAccountName=domain\5cuser`
`11:18:20,610 DEBUG [LDAPPasswordCredentialValidatorResult] LDAP error authenticating user in 'MyDC01'.  The response was interpreted as 'authn.srvr.msg.user.not.found'.`

What am I doing wrong? I have checked my datastore configs and the tests there work fine.

thanks

Comment: Here are additional config from my validator config:
`Search Base CN=Users,CN=Builtin,DC=MyDomain,DC=com`
`Search Filter sAMAccountName=${username}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I was referring to an empty OU in my password-validator config. Thanks to Federico from PingIdentity.